How to deploy an AdonisJS API to Vercel
I'm having trouble deploying my AdonisJS (v6) application to Vercel. Despite following the AdonisJS documentation, I haven't been able to resolve the issue.
The deployment process on Vercel completes successfully, but when I try to access the app I get a 404 Not Found error. I'm not sure if there's an issue with routing or configuration, but I can't figure out what's wrong.
Here is my Vercel project configuration :

And here is my scripts in my package.json :
"scripts": {
    "start": "node bin/server.js",
    "build": "node ace build",
    "dev": "node ace serve --hmr",
    "test": "node ace test",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "format": "prettier --write .",
    "typecheck": "tsc --noEmit"
  }`

I tried to search on forums, docs... but I could not find anything that helps!
